# SQL Server 2008 Licensing when splitting Report Manager and Report Service on different machines

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, licensing

Question:  If I install the Report Server webservice on machine A and I put the Report Manager web application on machine B ... do I need two licenses or just one?

In other words, what constitutes installing SSRS 2008 on a given machine?  Does the Reporting service = SSRS -OR- does any part of an SSRS install = SSRS with regards to licensing?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a very grey area.

My gut feel was that SSRS 'service' is what constitutes installing, but then you can never be too sure with Microsoft!

I haven't got 2008 server instance to look at, but on my 2005 Production server, which also runs 2005 SSRS, in the license file 
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\EULA\License_STD_ENU.txt'

it definitely states (bold highlighting my own)

> c.  Running Instances of the
>   Additional Software.  You may run or
>   otherwise use any number of instances
>   of additional software listed below on
>   any number of devices.  You may use
>   additional software only with the
>   server software directly, or
>   indirectly through other additional
>   software.
>
> - Analysis Services Shared Tools
> - Business Intelligence Development Studio
> - SQL Server 2005 Books Online
> - Connectivity Components
> - Legacy Components
> - Management Tools
> - Notification Services Client Components
> - **Reporting Services Report Manager**
> - Reporting Services Shared Tools
> - SQL Server 2005 Shared Tools
> - Software Development Kit
> - SQLXML Client Features
> - SQL Server Mobile Server Tools

so from that it would suggest that I can run SSRS Report Manager on another server, without needing a license

I would suggest checking out your EULA/License file

And if that isn't clear ask Microsoft!

Kev

**UPDATE**

The SQL 2008 page here http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx

and in the FAQ

> Q.  Do I need a separate license to run the SQL Server tools and analysis services?
>
> A.  No, a separate license is not required. However, any device that has SQL Server tools or technologies installed must have a valid SQL Server license.

I guess it comes back to this definition of 'installed'

Answer (score 2):

You need a license **for each client accessing the reporting manager**. The Report Manager will fall into the '[multiplexing](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/Special-Considerations.aspx#multiplexing)' category, no matter on which machine is installed. I am not aware of any 'special' treatment for Reporting Services vis-a-vis the multiplexing issue. Alternatively you need a per processor license that will cover an undetermined number of clients.

**Update:**

The case you describe is also covered from the pov of the server license in the same link. You need two separate server licenses too, in Scenario 2: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/Special-Considerations.aspx#reporting

This license page is a new one and I wasn't familiar with the new details they added for reporting, sry.

Comment: even if you had processor licensing?

Comment: per processor is entirely different thing. Clearly don't need per server and per client licenses anymore, but I think you will need a per-processor for the reporting server machine processors too, and that will cost you a fortune.

Comment: so in a per-processor model, where the reporting server is licensed, do you still need another license if you wanted to host the report manager on another machine?

Comment: Wouldn't this fall exactly into Scenario 2 in the link in my post?

Comment: No - Scenario 2 talks about splitting the Report Server from the Report Server database. Not specifically about splitting the Report Manager from the Report Server.  Plus this is a SQL2005 specific document - there is no equivalent on the SQL2008 pages.  I still think the best answer is to ask Microsoft

Comment: Obviously contacting MS is the best and pretty much only serious option. It serves though to do homework, sales reps are sales reps and will try to extract the most you can pay no matter what u need... My understanding is that if only the Report Manager is run from a separate machine then it will be a 'device', ie. needs a client CAL for itself, a CAL for each client accessing the RM (multiplexing), but no license if Reporting Server is per-processor.

Answer (score 0):

> BUSINESS INTELLIGENCE / COMPONENTS IN ADDITIONAL SERVERS
>
> The Business Intelligence components for SQL Server 2008 include Analysis Services, Reporting Services, and Integration Services. To use any of these components, the server on which Business Intelligence is installed must have a valid SQL Server 2008 license. If these components are in a separate server than the main database server, then they require an additional license of each additional server where they are installed.

Comment: Is it an answer or a basically quoted text from somewhere?